# Passing output from one command as argument to another

Tags: unix, shell, awk, grep, design-patterns

I have this *for*:

```
for i in `ls -1 access.log*`; do tail $i |awk {'print $4'} |cut -d: -f 1 |grep - $i > $i.output; done
```

**ls** will give access.log, access.log.1, access.log.2 etc.
**tail** will give me the last line of each file, which looks like: `192.168.1.23 - - [08/Oct/2010:14:05:04 +0300]` etc. etc. etc
**awk+cut** will extract the date (08/Oct/2010 - but different in each access.log), which will allow me to **grep** for it and redirect the output to a separate file.

But I cannot seem to pass the output of awk+cut to grep.

The reason for all this is that those access logs include lines with more than one date (06/Oct, 07/Oct, 08/Oct) and I just need the lines with the most recent date.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some example input and expected output?

Comment: One problem is that you keep overwriting the same output for each access.log. Note that you can also use multiple files for tail.

Comment: lol.. you're right, don't know how I overlooked this fact. Let me think about it so I can come up with a workaround.

Comment: just add a counter which is appended to the log name

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the feedback, but this question was asked in 2010.

Comment: We mark as duplicate in order to collect the relevant information in one place. The clarity of the question and the answers is more important than their age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a sidenote, `tail` displays the last 10 lines.

A possible solution would be to `grep`this way:

```
for i in `ls -lf access.log*`; do grep $(tail $i |awk {'print $4'} |cut -d: -f 1| sed 's/\[/\\[/') $i > $i.output; done
```

Comment: I don't quite care about this aspect. I could have used tail -n 1.

Comment: @mouviciel - I already tried it exactly as you wrote it, but it gives grep: Unmatched [ or [^

Comment: I see, `[` has a special meaning for `grep`. I edit my answer.

Comment: sed 's#\\[##g' - this one works. Nonetheless, I'm still curious about my initial question

Comment: It seems that this is the only solution, to write all the other commands inside the one you need. So, in my case, it is: for i in \`ls -lf access.log*`; do grep $(tail $i |awk {'print $4'} |cut -d: -f 1| sed 's#\[##g') $i > $i.output; done. Thanks for the support.

Comment: The output from `ls -l` is a big long line; you do not want to pass that whole thing to `tail`!

Comment: why not? you think that tail is gonna get sick? fine, ls -1 instead of -l. this wasn't actually the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you break it up into steps??

```
for file in *access.log
do
  what=$(tail "$i" |awk {'print $4'} |cut -d: -f 1)
  grep "$what" "$file" >> output
done
```

Comment: This, too, overwrites `output` in every iteration.

Comment: I guess I can break it up, but wanted to run it from CLI. Anyhow, It's been more than one time that I needed to use a feature like this, so I'm trying to find the answer for my scenario.

Comment: The elegant solution is to redirect the `done` to overwrite the file; this way, the entire loop body is redirected, and the file is opened for writing just once, intead of repeatedly inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `ls` that way. Also, `ls -l` gives you information you don't need. The `-f` option to `grep` will allow you to pipe the pattern to `grep`. Always quote variables that contain filenames.

```
for i in access.log*; do awk 'END {sub(":.*","",$4); print substr($4,2)}' "$i" | grep -f - $i > "$i.output"; done
```

I also eliminated `tail` and `cut` since AWK can do their jobs.

Comment: I see no problem with ls -l, it's how I've got used to use it. I could have used ls -1, but it is so not important. AWK isn't a good candidate for tail and cut's job because AWK reads the whole file to get to the END, and when one has 500+mb of files, it takes too long. Now about the grep -f, that really is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs explains why `ls` is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Umm...
Use xargs or backticks.

```
man xargs
```

or
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html , section 3.4.5. Command substitution

Comment: I don't see how xargs can help me. It would need to know what the output from all the prior commands is and then pass it as a pattern to grep. It would not be `command | xargs grep 123 file.txt`, but it would be `command | xargs grep -pattern-from-command- file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
 grep "$(stuff to get piped over to be grep-ed)" file
```

I haven't tried this, but my answer applied here would look like this:

```
 grep "$(for i in `ls -1 access.log*`; do tail $i |awk {'print $4'} |cut -d: -f 1 |grep - $i > $i.output; done)" $i
```